# EigenFace Recognition using JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to achieve Face Recognition and got here :-

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMat;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.MatVector;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui;

public class Eigen {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
long size=6;
MatVector imgs=new MatVector(size);
int[] id={0,0,0,0,0,0};

FaceRecognizer fr=opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
{
    String url="C:/Users/user/Desktop/a3.png";
    IplImage img=opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage(url);
}
fr.train(imgs,id);
IplImage testImage=opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage("C:/Users/vivek/Documents/NetBeansProjects/face/src/testimg/hello.png");
CvMat mat= testImage.asCvMat();
int val=fr.predict(mat);
System.out.println(val);
}
}
```

But this code gives me Runtime Error each time I run it :-
Output

> OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus
>   its number of rows can not be changed) in cv::Mat::reshape, file
>   ........\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 802 Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   ........\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:802: error: (-13) The
>   matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed
>   in function cv::Mat::reshape

I have gray scaled both the images and they are of same dimension 200*200.But it still shows this error can anybody help.